# View model issue in Asp.net mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models data .
please take a look

```
 public class StoreTransactionAngular
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public int TargetId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        [MustHaveOneElementAttribute(ErrorMessage = "At least a task is required")]
        [MinLength(1)]
        [EnsureOneElement(ErrorMessage = "At least a person is required")]
        public List<StoreTransactionDetails> Details { get; set; }        
    }

    public class StoreTransactionDetails
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public bool IsUsed { get; set; }
        public string IsUsedText { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to store my data to another table

```
public class StoreTransaction
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public int TargetId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        //public List<StoreTransactionDetails> Details { get; set; }
        public string ItemIds { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public string Quantities { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public string IsUseds { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it possible to do so , I have a following view.cshtml code

```
@model  StoresManagement.ViewModel.StoreTransactionAngular
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Store Transaction Manage";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajaxForm", ng_controller = "IncomeController" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Transaction Data
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StoreId, (SelectList)ViewBag.StoreList, "Select Store", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TargetId, (SelectList)ViewBag.VendorList, "Select Vendor", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TargetId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TransactionDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Date", ng_model = "date" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TransactionDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Transaction Details
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select ng_model="ItemId" ng-options="p as p.label for p in ItemId" id="ItemId" name="ItemId" class="form-control">
                        <option unit="" value="">Select Item</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng_model="IsUsed" name="IsUsed" id="IsUsed" />
                        Is Used؟
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 relative">
                    <input type="number" ng_model="Quantity" step="0.01" min="0" max="9999999999" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" placeholder="Quanitity" class="form-control" />
                    <span ng_model="Unit" class="Unit"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <button id="btnAddItem" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>



                </div>

            </div>
            <hr />
            <table id="tblItems" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th width="20%">Status</th>
                        <th width="20%">Quantity</th>
                        <th width="3%"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemId)<br />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)<br />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)<br />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                    <tr ng-repeat="ItemModel in ListItem">
                        <td>{{ItemModel.ItemName}}</td>
                        <td>{{ItemModel.IsUsedText }}</td>
                        <td>{{ItemModel.Quantity}} {{ ItemModel.Unit }}</td>

                        <td width="10%" class="text-right">
                            <div classn-group btn-group-justified">
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="getCustomer(ItemModel)">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" ng-click="deleteCustomer(ItemModel)">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                There is no Item selected
            </div>
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemIds)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Quantities)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsUseds)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"> </i> Save</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancle", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-default", data_dismiss = "modal" })
}
```

This part is not working

```
@*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemIds)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Quantities)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsUseds)*@
```

can anyone help me with this part to make it working , as these values are necessary to do so .

Thanks in advance, Need more details you can ask via comments

Comment: What the definition of `not working`? Model class for the view is `StoreTransactionAngular` and it doesn't have these properties.

Comment: Yes I know that can you plese let me know how to solve the issue , I need to get values from above two models and want to save these values to StoreTranaction table

Comment: Are you trying to do model binding where the first two tables provide the input, but the post method tries to bind to the third? If so, maybe show your post method signature too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your view model to

```
public class StoreTransactionAngular
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public int TargetId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [MustHaveOneElementAttribute(ErrorMessage = "At least a task is required")]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [EnsureOneElement(ErrorMessage = "At least a person is required")]
    public List<StoreTransactionDetails> Details { get; set; }    

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string ItemIds { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string Quantities { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Labels), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string IsUseds { get; set; }    
}
```

Open the comment for

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemIds)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Quantities)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsUseds)
```

Now you can use JS to set value to ItemIds, Quantities, and IsUseds. Once you click the submit, you will get the values in your view model as the parameter in your backend action.

---

Updated above.

Your view model is StoreTransactionAngular and it doesn't contain ItemIds, Quantities, and IsUseds. That's why the error occured.

The simplest way is adding the "StoreTransaction" into your view model. Then your can popuate and handle the values after your click the submit button in your action.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add store transaction to view model

Comment: I have another values that are coming through another models

Comment: @seriouscoder I've updated the answer.

Comment: is this help to solve the values to another table

Comment: Why not? In your backend action, you can build up another object and use the new object to insert into your table.

Comment: yes  working fine